# Website using just index.php and database

Tags: php, html, seo

I'm working on creating an image gallery with just the index.php 
The users can switch between images by using "next" or "previous" buttons.

Is this healthy for the server ?

Does this method harm SEO as no html pages really exist except for a blank template. ( All the SEO related data are in the mysql DB)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your server does not need html code to sustain its health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practice of having a single page website will not by default harm your site's page rank, although it does add some issues.

- Only one URL - usually sites have /about, /contact, /gallery, /we'r'awesome, etc. You get one. (You could use hash tags as a practical workaround, but this wont do much for SEO - if you designate each hash tag as unique content and it all points to one page of the same content, this can actually hurt you)
- Best SEO practice is to have one set of content/keywords per page. With a one page sit, you only get one go at it.
- Additionally, a single page may take longer to load (depending how you set it up), and be less intuitive to navigate (gain, depending how it's set up).

Check out [this article](http://www.awwwards.com/seo-optimization-for-parallax-scrolling-websites.html) for some more points.

Comment: The index page is an empty template. The title and image link are delivered through the database. 
Are you implying that having a Unique HTML file with it's image and description is a better idea ? Can this be generated on a large scale.

Comment: Whether the content is provided from a database or static pages is really not relevant to SEO. SEO deals with the final result of the page (pre-Java/Script loading, generally). As evidence, Joomla and Wordpress both have a single page (index.php) which draws in any number of separate pages of content with no negative impact on SEO.

Comment: I was referring to a website with a single page (one that included about, contact, gallery, etc all on one page). Sounds like that's not what you mean, apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can harm SEO, but a lot of things can so that should be the last thing you focus on since Google is all that matters now and it changes often.
You can fix that by adding "tutorial" and "about" pages and what not anyways.

Healthy for the server depends on your code and the server and the amount of visitors and how you store the images etc etc etc etc.